# Selecting row from many to many relation table which have two foreign key from two table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I'm sorry for my bad title, because I confuse to choose the title. But I hope the description can explain it. I want to select value from relation table which have foreign key to two tables although the data of relation table is null, so there's my table

I have three tables :

```
Student
==========
id || name
===============
1  || Rooney
2  || Carrick
3  || Smalling
4  || De Gea
```

Then :

```
Item
==========
id || Title
===============
1  || Pre-Test
2  || Post-Test
3  || Final-Test
```

Then a table for many to many relation

```
Score
==========
id || student_id || item_id || Score
=====================================
1  || 1          || 1       || 100
2  || 1          || 2       || 80
3  || 2          || 1       || 90
4  || 2          || 3       || 85
5  || 3          || 2       || 80
6  || 3          || 3       || 90
7  || 4          || 1       || 95
```

And I want to get result like this :

```
Result
==========
score_id || student_name || item_name || Score
================================================
1        || Rooney       || Pre-Test  || 100
2        || Rooney       || Post-Test || 80
NULL     || Rooney       || Final-Test|| NULL
3        || Carrick      || Pre-Test  || 90
NULL     || Carrick      || Post-Test || NULL
4        || Carrick      || Final-Test|| 85
NULL     || Smalling     || Pre-Test  || NULL
5        || Smalling     || Post-Test || 80
6        || Smalling     || Final-Test|| 90
7        || De Gea       || Pre-Test  || 95
NULL     || De Gea       || Post-Test || NULL
NULL     || De Gea       || Final-Test|| NULL
```

I have search some tutorial from another forum for outer join and try it in my database, but the query didn't show the null value. Thanks,

*)Edited

I've try query with union and join, but the result didn't show the null values

```
SELECT score.id AS score_id, student.name, item.title, score.score
FROM student
RIGHT JOIN score ON student.id = score.student_id
RIGHT JOIN item ON score.item_id = item.id
UNION 
SELECT score.id AS score_id, student.name, item.title, score.score
FROM item
RIGHT JOIN score ON score.item_id = item.id
RIGHT JOIN student ON score.student_id = student.id
ORDER BY score_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

and

```
SELECT score.id AS score_id, student.name AS student_name, item.title AS item_title, score.score
FROM student
LEFT JOIN score ON student.id = score.student_id
LEFT JOIN item ON score.item_id = item.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

change to right join still didn't show the null values, here's the result :

```
score_id || student_name || item_title || score
1        || Rooney       || Pre-Test   || 100
2        || Rooney       || Post-Test  || 80
3        || Carrick      || Pre-Test   || 90
4        || Carrick      || Final-Test || 85
5        || Smalling     || Post-Test  || 80
7        || Smalling     || Final-Test || 90
8        || De Gea       || Pre-Test   || 95
```

Comment: Have you tried RIGHT JOIN ?

Comment: Post what u've tried so far

Comment: yes, i've tried the right join but null values didn't show up @StanislavL

Comment: yes, i've edited the question and add some query @sagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    sc.id AS score_id, 
    s.name AS student_name, 
    i.title AS item_name, 
    sc.score 
FROM student s
CROSS JOIN item i
LEFT JOIN score sc ON sc.item_id = i.id AND sc.student_id = s.id;
```

Comment: wow, it's work well! the result same with my expectation , i never know about cross join, just know inner, right and left outer join.. thanks! :D